# Login page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, single-page-application

I've got a web application where all interactions require logging in. I see at least two ways of implementing a login page view in AngularJS.

One is to use a separate view: let say I'm using [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and define a top-level view with two states: login and dashboard.

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "partials/login.html"
    })
    .state('mainpage', {
      url: "/mainpage",
      templateUrl: "partials/mainpage.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        …
      }
    });
```

Second is to just make use of ng-if:

```
<span ng-if="loggedin">
  … my main page …
</span>
<span ng-if="!loggedin">
  … login page …
</span>
```

I see that the second option will easily allow users to link to specific sections of their pages, with the login page showing up as necessary automatically, whereas the first option will require me to code some redirection stuff to make this happen.

However, for some reason I feel the first option is cleaner, even if I cannot provide any reasonable arguments now.

I'm starting with AngularJS now, so I don't have enough experience to decide on any of these options. Which one is more desirable?

Comment: How will you maintain the login data?  On the server as a session data?

Comment: I can't think of many use cases where the second option is acceptable.

Comment: @Jess: does it actually matter? In this case, the app uses websockets to connect to the server, send authentication data (login, password, one-time password from a token) and receives a token cookie which can be used to reload page without logging in for an hour. The token cookie is stored in some kind of browser local storage. The `loggedin` variable is a boolean that basically says the current token cookie is still valid.

Comment: @Shomz: can you explain the drawbacks, then?

Answer (score 9):

I answered a similar question here: [AngularJS Authentication + RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325324/angularjs-authentication-restful-api)

---

I've written an [AngularJS module](https://github.com/userapp-io/userapp-angular) for [UserApp](https://www.userapp.io/) that supports protected/public routes, rerouting on login/logout, heartbeats for status checks, stores the session token in a cookie, directives for signup/login/logout, etc.

https://github.com/userapp-io/userapp-angular

You could either:

1. Modify the module and attach it to your own API, or
2. Use the module together with [UserApp](https://www.userapp.io/) (a cloud-based user management API)

If you use UserApp, you won't have to write any server-side code for the user stuff (more than validating a token). Take the [course on Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-v2b3k) to try it out.

Here's some examples of how it works:

- **How to specify which routes that should be public, and which route that is the login form:**

  ```
  $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', public: true, login: true});
  $routeProvider.when('/signup', {templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html', public: true});
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'});
  ```

  The `.otherwise()` route should be set to where you want your users to be redirected after login. Example:

  `$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});`
- **Login form with error handling:**

  ```
  <form ua-login ua-error="error-msg">
      <input name="login" placeholder="Username"><br>
      <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"><br>
      <button type="submit">Log in</button>
      <p id="error-msg"></p>
  </form>
  ```
- **Signup form with error handling:**

  ```
  <form ua-signup ua-error="error-msg">
    <input name="first_name" placeholder="Your name"><br>
    <input name="login" ua-is-email placeholder="Email"><br>
    <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"><br>
    <button type="submit">Create account</button>
    <p id="error-msg"></p>
  </form>
  ```
- **Log out link:**

  `<a href="#" ua-logout>Log Out</a>`

  (Ends the session and redirects to the login route)
- **Access user properties:**

  User properties are accessed using the `user` service, e.g: `user.current.email`

  Or in the template: `<span>{{ user.email }}</span>`
- **Hide elements that should only be visible when logged in:**

  `<div ng-show="user.authorized">Welcome {{ user.first_name }}!</div>`
- **Show an element based on permissions:**

  `<div ua-has-permission="admin">You are an admin</div>`

And to authenticate to your back-end services, just use `user.token()` to get the session token and send it with the AJAX request. At the back-end, use the [UserApp API](https://app.userapp.io/#/docs/) (if you use UserApp) to check if the token is valid or not.

If you need any help, just let me know :)

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but your reply does not actually answer the question: why this solution is better than other. Could you add some information as to why would one prefer to use routes over ngIf?

Comment: Sorry about that! Template are there to separate things, so we don't have to place all the HTML code in one file. As your markup grows, it's pretty neat to separate those into it's own files. Hope I answered your question :)

Comment: So, why couldn't I just use ng-include to separate the login part to a separate template, if it is the separation that is such a big concern?

Comment: ng-include will always load the file, even when you don't need it. If you create a route, that template file will only be loaded when that route is used.

Comment: I'm already compiling all the templates into JS-based cache, which is always loaded, so that doesn't make any difference for me.

Comment: @TimothyE.Johansson UserApp is behaving weird with me, and I was wondering if you could help. The login page works but doe not redirect anywhere. Allso "user.authorized" returns true but when i use "ng-show" with it, it doesn't respond to changes in user.authorized

Answer (score 3):

The first option is absolutely the way to go, the only place I would see using the `ng-if` is maybe in your header menu and footer to dynamically update links if needed. Secondly the first option is the best because you could abstract out the template and the controller, you would be able to set these in the route giving you a much better separation of concerns.

Comment: So, just “separation of concerns”?

Comment: in other words you can have a module based framework, if you had login you could have a login controller and login template and load them in the <ng-view></ng-view> and then once logged in you would route to /admin and have a admin controller (most likely with more child controllers) and an admin dashboard template, this again would be updated by the router, what this does is separate everything, if you need to make a change to login you exactly where to look for your controller and your template, its much cleaner than using if statements, if statements make everything too tightly coupled