# Angular Facebook app, want to save both login status for different pages

Tags: facebook, angularjs, facebook-login

I have an angular app generated by yeoman,and it has two pages.
And I set a routeProvider for these two pages:

```
angular
    .module('fbPostApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .when('/friend-filter', {
                templateUrl: 'views/friend-filter.html',
                controller: 'FriendFilterCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        });
    });
```

MainCtrl:

```
function MainCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $scope.login = function(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
            $scope.uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            $scope.accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            login_success($scope.uid,$scope.accessToken);
        });
    };
    var require = 'friends_birthday,friends_about_me,friends_relationships,friends_likes,read_stream,user_about_me,publish_stream';
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            $scope.uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            $scope.accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            login_success($scope.uid, $scope.accessToken);
        };
    },{scope:require});
    ...
```

FriendFilterCtrl:

```
function FriendFilterCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        var require = 'friends_birthday,friends_about_me,friends_relationships,friends_likes,friends_about_me';
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                $scope.uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                var userURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+uid+"";
                var dataURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+uid+"?fields=friends.fields(birthday,name,relationship_status)&access_token="+accessToken+"";
                ...
```

I now set both pages a login function,and when I switch to another page I will login "again".But I want that I only need to login once at any page, and can still ajax data when I switch to another one.How to do that??

Comment: You don't want two `.otherwise` calls as second one replaces the first one. There can only be one `.otherwise` call, that will be used when no other route definition matches.

Answer (score 1):

### User authentication service

For authentication purposes one creates a service that provides authentication functionality as well as user status. Then consume your service in your controllers.

```
angular.module("fbPostApp")
       .service("UserAuthentication", function() {
           ...
       });
```

There are [several](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app) [examples](http://www.frederiknakstad.com/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/) of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623813/75642) on the [web](http://net-daylight.blogspot.com/2013/11/deal-with-authentication-in-angularjs.html) that will help you understand and get started with your own implementation.

The one that actually implements FB authentication can be read [here](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/facebook-authentication-in-your-angularjs-web-app). And there's also a [GitHub project (Angular Facebook Utils)](https://github.com/davidchang/angular-facebook-utils) that implements it in a reusable way.

Comment: upvote. also check out angular-easyfb: https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb

Answer (score -1):

If you like to have a detailed instruction on how to integrate FacebookAPI into AngularJs you might consider reading this article.

http://www.boynux.com/angularjs-facebook-integration/

That simply creates a Facebook modules that you can easily use in your application.
Then you can call login only once, and use the same info in all pages.

Alternatively (this is what personally do) you can wrap that Facebook Modules into another service and use that throughout your app. This should be much cleaner.